weird characters on visual studio code preview and tooltip
I use vscode on macos sonoma (14.5) and having issue with both tooltip while checking via (nodejs) package.json file.

as well as checking extension details

I have reset to default setting by clear out settings.json but this issue still exists

seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78577349/11107541
